# heroku build succeed but url gives application error while heroku open

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, heroku-cli

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 327 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  8.11.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   5.6.0
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.11.1...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.11.1...
remote:        npm 5.6.0 already installed with node
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        up to date in 4.243s
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote:
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        Skipping because npm 5.6.0 sometimes fails when running 'npm 
prune' due to a known issue
remote:        https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19356
remote:
remote:        You can silence this warning by updating to at least npm 5.7.1 in your package.json
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-an-npm-version
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 28.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v6
remote:        https://ashishkr.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/ashishkr.git
cfc5c8a..76b27d1  master -> master
```

I have also a Procfile in my project root and have like:

```
web: node server.js
```

on doing heroku config i get the following result :
    MONGODB_URI: mongodb://:@ds163410.mlab.com:63410/ashishkr

i hide the username and password for the security concern but i am sure that the username and password which i have entered is absolutely correct!

in my package.json i have engines and start script also:

```
 "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node server.js"
  },
 "engines": {
 "node": "8.11.1",
 "npm": "5.6.0"
  },
```

Anykind of help is appreciated !!

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you pls add the server.js

Comment: Did you try heroku ps:scale web=1 Check if atleast one instance of application is working.

Comment: yeah sure sandeep !

Comment: @SandeepRanjan server.js is too long to comment!!

Comment: heroku ps:scale web=1  giving success that app is running at free:1